# How do i use JMeter to support 250 users, with 100 concurrently

Tags: jmeter

** Currently working on performance test however require perform load test to support 250 users, with 100 concurrently **

Answer (score 0):

Information provided is limited.
As I understand you have 250 test users who will do login operation. Amongst these, 100 have to be concurrent. Your thread group configuration should looks something like this. Refer this JMeter documentation for more details - [Thread Groups](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html).
[image]

Comment: Hi Rahul,  Thank you for providing to my answer to but there is less information to the question but what I know is that the requirement is for  250 users to execute 100 concurrently.